# ASP.Net Core 2 Ignore JWT authorization for localhost requests

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, authorization

I have ASP.Net core 2 WebApi hosted on IIS which protected by JWT Authorization. Is there any way to allow localhost requests access to API without authorization? i.e requests from nodejs app on same server.

Comment: Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72612217 , you shouldn't delete questions you're interested in being answered, even if they are downvoted. It was deleted the moment before the comment could be posted. The question is off-topic on SO but could possibly fit softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Any way, the way you deal with templates determine the choice. It's Vue. Other frameworks are limited in this case. You may want to reconsider the requirement regarding storing templates in db because it can be unjustified and so make the app weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can validate localhost request in `OnMessageReceived` of JWT events and set `Principal` for context and call `context.Success()` like this:

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
      ...
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {

        // jwt auth.
        services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
          options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
          options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
          ...
          cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
          {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
              var ip = context.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
              if (ip == "127.0.0.1" || ip == "::1")
              {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                  new Claim(
                      ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                      "LocalHostUser",
                      ClaimValueTypes.String,
                      context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                  new Claim(
                      ClaimTypes.Name,
                      "LocalHostUser",
                      ClaimValueTypes.String,
                      context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                };

                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                    new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                context.Success();
              }
              return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
          };
        });
      }
    }
```